# Highcharts: only display stack labels if there are multiple stacks?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Screenshot of issue:

[Stack Labels (current view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjlMV.png)

I tried the code below, but it isn't working for me. Any ideas?

```
stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    if (this.x !== this.total)
                    return this.total;
                }
             },
```

Maybe I have to use 'this.points' since the data series involves arrays of numbers.

Comment: please give better clarification of your question

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: Sample data is just something like [1, null, 5, 3, 2].

Comment: My question rephrased is this: How do I hide the stack labels if there is only one data column to show? 

(Because it's redundant to display 2 in a column and then 2 again right above it as the total)

Comment: by setting you can only show or hide the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with this it should works :

```
...
formatter: function() {
   var data = 0;
   for (key in this.points) {
       if (this.points[key] !== null) data++;
   }

   if (data > 2) {
       return this.total;
   }

}
...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/0jy1oxwv/)